# Importing a RSA public key into python when in strong form

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa, public-key

Essentially what I have here is a key from a ssh-rsa generator that was given to me in the form of a string as follows

```
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCsjE+uDO0v+il18nmkF0dJZaXOZVKfg7TG9l9Aod0rDiw2pNoQqCUHFGDE1HYXhK6NfVtCZdNDF+kF89EV9eygiN3RVPm5cwum45apT8N+mZsveA5JhzUoFMCSYpb7uGoQC/2C9eLLlExjSL50USTwNknx7NJKseNsZ1UnYPzVBOPv7DqGtI7Xuap80PloePuJ0kIJBL0SXGQFG1pw2zpb8KLy1OAcKLo9Q5clKNU3xAzl7FWs4JjvYjUfqTeUM1JLUx2CRqZYdzAVkxWBEfIE87hl96r0IWwYMOMOg4YH4VZ8944YNdPtUQTf4pGmaYNN11QVUTX/1mM/S3N8mbDF
```

I know that this is a valid RSA public key, but what I really to get is n and e out of it. However, when I attempt to import it into my python code as so

```
import Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

f = open('MyRSAKey.txt', 'r')
Temp_Key = f.read()
Final_Key = RSA.importKey(Temp_Key)
n = Final_Key.n
e = Final_key.e
```

I get an error that says

```
 ValueError: RSA key format is not supported
```

Is there something that I am missing? I just really to find some way to get a hold of n and e so I can store them for future use

Comment: Usually, an RSA public key has `ssh-rsa ` at the beginning. Maybe you could try adding that. For example, one of my keys starts with `ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC`.

Comment: @zondo Aha! Thank you very much that solved the issue!

Comment: @zondo Could you convert your comment into an answer? It's fairly basic, but every developer has been staring at "basic" issues for hours at a time :) - I'm not sure if I agree with the close votes for that reason.

Answer (score 2):

I just added

```
"ssh-rsa " + "AAAAB..."
```

and it worked